# JSON file is converted to string while using json.load in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a valid JSON file but when i am using json.load(), it gets converted to string instead of Python dictionary.

My JSON string:

```
{
  "colors": [
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FFF"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,255,1],
        "hex": "#00F"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "secondary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#0F0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It is named as `color.json`

My Python code is:

```
import json
with open("color.json") as f:
    data=json.load(f)
print(type(data))
```

It shows output as class 'str'. why is it not being converted to dictionary?

Comment: Using your code, I get a `<class 'dict'>`.

Comment: Look at your [mcve], and your actual code, and try to figure out what you've done wrong there because this works without any issues.

Comment: Your code's just fine.

Comment: My code is exactly same..can such probelm arise because of ide? ihave spyder installed

Answer (score 0):

I have extended  your code as below with your provided json file

```
import json
with open("color.json") as f:
    data=json.load(f)
print(type(data))

listofkeys=[keys for keys in data.keys()]
print(listofkeys)

color_keys=[keys2 for keys2 in data["colors"][0].keys()]
print(color_keys)
```

And Output is as below

```
<class 'dict'>
['colors']
['category', 'color', 'code', 'type']
```

First thing is it is returning `dict` type only. And it is having only one key `colors` as we have printed out.

And Second thing is this colors key is having list of dictionaries as its value which are as well printed in our code. `category color code type` are four dictionaries

And you can further explore these dictionaries.

and the above mentioned code is working in both python2 and 3 versions. Check again.